# Code Not displaying answers fields for questions in survey app on laravel 5.6

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I have used form class to add question with radio button options answers in my app but my form only displays question test box not displays radio button or checkbox for options and neither displays answer text box.
    {{$survey->title}}

```
{{$survey->description}} Created by: {{$survey->user->name}}

{!! Form::open(array('action'=>array('AnswerController@store',$survey->id)))!!} @forelse($survey->questions as $key=>$question)
Question {{$key+1}} - {{$question->title}}

@if($question->question_type==='text') Answer @elseif($question->question_type==='textarea') Textarea @elseif($question->question_type==='radio') @foreach($question->option_name as $key=>$value)
                  <p style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
                  <input name="{{$question->id}}[answer]" type="radio" id="{{ $key }}" />
                  <label for="{{$key}}">{{$value}}</label>
                  </p>
                  @endforeach
                  @elseif($question->question_type==='checkbox')
                  @foreach($question->option_name as $key=>$value)
                  <p style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="something{{$key}}" name="{{$question->id}}[answer]"/>
                  <label for="something{{$key}}">{{$value}}</label>
                  </p>
                  @endforeach
                  @endif
                  <div class="divider" style="margin:10px 10px;"></div>
                  @empty
        <span class='flow-text center-align'>Nothing to show</span>
      @endforelse
      {{Form::submit('Submit Survey',array('class'=>'btn waves-effect waves-light'))}} 
      {!!Form::close()!!}
      </div>here
```

Comment: Have you try to display value of question type?`$question->question_type`??

Comment: Laravel 5 removed the form helper. I guess you updated from a previous version. Are you using `laravelcollective/html`?

Comment: yes laravelcollective/html

Comment: I have solved that problem but their is another issue when I start adding answers in survey It is not saving answers on radio buttons and check boxes and only one question with checkbox or radio button on top of form is selected.It saves only one question at a time or some times null or "on" keyword againist checkbox or radio answers.